# splice in Immutability Helpers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

Please tell how can I write the same but without indexes before splice. Is it possible?

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];


let c = update(a, {0:{$splice: [[0,1]] },1:{$splice: [[0,1]] }, 2:{$splice: [[0,1]] }, 3:{$splice: [[0,1]] }})
console.log(c)
```

[link jsfiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj8qvd9c/8/)

I need delete one element from each array, but general array will be dynamical. 
Is there syntax for splice where I can do not write index of each array? and update will understand

Comment: is there a special reason you cant just use `a.map(array => array.slice(1, array.length))`

Comment: no, I need to use splice from immutability helper library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const update = immutabilityHelper;

let a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
let c = update(a, {$apply: el => el.map(inner => update(inner, {$splice: [[0, 1]]}))})
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
console.log(JSON.stringify(c))
```

```html
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/immutability-helper?.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/preact@latest/dist/preact.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, already did like this. Mark your answer as right.